# JAVA - Existe alguma maneira de enviar uma impressão pro Spool do Windows?

Tags: java, android, windows, impressora

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma maneira de enviar uma impressão pro Spooler do Windows via java... Tentei via Socket, PrintWriter e tudo mais, porém não consigo enviar pro Spool, apenas diretamente pra impressora!!!!

Comment: Qual seria utilidade de passar algo ao Spooler e não para a impressora diretamente ?

Comment: Vários aparelhos usando a mesma aplicação ao mesmo tempo na rede, com um servidor principal rodando o banco de dados e conectado as impressoras (seriam mais de uma no caso)... Para que as requisições de impressão executem em fila e eu não perca nenhuma impressão...

Comment: Vamos supor que na empresa tem 20 celulares e todos enviando impressão ao mesmo tempo para uma única impressora. Isso já complicaria a situação, agora imagina uma empresa com 100 aparelhos enviando requisições de impressão ao mesmo tempo!!! Seria ideal usar o spooler do servidor pra comandar a fila e a sequencia de impressão.... Eu criei uma aplicação android que se comunica com um WebService em java para poder imprimir, porém não consegui enviar a impressão pro spooler e nos testes algumas impressões foram perdidas por falta desse controle.....

Comment: Entendi, realmente era curiosidade já que não vi nada assim. valeu por ter explicado.

Comment: Não mexo muito com java tradicional, mas se o webservice foi construido em java, será que resolve a questão esta página do docs da oracle? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jps/spec/jpsOverview.fm4.html